# How get balance in Clickatell Platform (not old accounts use "Development archive")

Tags: clickatell

Can get balance for old  accounts [REST API DOC](https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/retrieve-balance-rest/)
Can`t [get balance use new API of Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-request-parameters/)

Comment: Did you ever manage to get hold of API for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Clickatell support team;

> There is currently no API call to get your balance from within your
>   account.

They suggest you log in and check on their website. :(